# How to mount a File Storage volume to an azure container instance using REST api

Tags: c#, azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to create an Azure container instance and mounting a File Storage volume via REST API, but I'm getting 400 response.

I'm able to create the container and keep it running but when I add the volume part it returns a 400 response (Bad request) without further explanation

Here is the JSON payload I'm sending to the REST endpoint:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/111111111/resourceGroups/OraResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/solver",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "name": "solver",
  "properties": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "azureFile": {
          "shareName": "orafileshare",
          "storageAccountKey": "somekey",
          "storageAccountName": "myaccountname"
        },
        "name": "Volume1"
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "solver",
        "properties": {
          "command": [],
          "environmentVariables": [],
          "image": "acraccount/solver:v1",
          "ports": [
            {
              "port": 12345
            }
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "cpu": 1.0,
              "memoryInGB": 1.5
            }
          },
          "volumeMounts": [
            {
              "name": "Volume1",
              "mountPath": "/mountFolder"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "imageRegistryCredentials": [
      {
        "password": "123123123213123",
        "server": "acr.server.io",
        "username": "acrOra"
      }
    ],
    "ipAddress": {
      "ports": [
        {
          "protocol": "TCP",
          "port": 12345
        }
      ],
      "type": "Public"
    },
    "osType": "Linux",
    "restartPolicy": "Always"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
}
```

The expected results is a 200 or 201 response and the container should appear on my Azure portal dashboard but the actual response is 400.

Comment: The documentation for `mountPath` is "The path within the container where the volume should be mounted", but you have provided the URL of the file share. See the [example request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate#containergroupscreateorupdate) in the docs.

Comment: @nlawalker I changed mountPath to /mountFolder but still bad request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with this correction. I also received 400 bad request but later corrected it and I was able to run it successfully.

1. Name of volume, capital letter is not allowed.

`Change "Volume1" to "volume1"`

Reference Error :

`{"error":{"code":"InvalidVolumeName","message":"The volume name 'Volume1' is invalid. The volume name must match the regex '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?' (e.g. 'my-name')."}}`

1. Sku is not a valid property, Remove it

   `{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request
   content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find
   member 'sku' on object of type 'ComputeResources'. Path
   'properties.containers[0].properties.resources.requests.sku', line 32,
   position 22.'."}}`

   Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate#resourcerequests

Sample configuration

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/teststoragerest/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/solver",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "name": "demo1forrahul",
  "properties": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "azureFile": {
          "shareName": "testfilestorage",
          "storageAccountKey": "xxxx",
          "storageAccountName": "xxxxxx"
        },
        "name": "volume1"
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "demo1forrahul",
        "properties": {
          "command": [],
          "environmentVariables": [],
          "image": "nginx",
          "ports": [
            {
              "port": 80
            }
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "cpu": 1.0,
              "memoryInGB": 1.5
            }
          },
          "volumeMounts": [
            {
              "name": "volume1",
              "mountPath": "/testfolder"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "imageRegistryCredentials": [],
    "ipAddress": {
      "ports": [
        {
          "protocol": "TCP",
          "port": 80
        }
      ],
      "type": "Public"
    },
    "osType": "Linux",
    "restartPolicy": "Always"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
}
```

Comment: I declare you a life savior .